# how to validate table column values in python or in MySQL

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, database

i am trying to validate values(length of values)that to store in MySQL DB

I Created DB using python
Created Table called rawdata
inserting also but

For example: Deviceid column is there, i want to validate that deviceid value, deviceid digits should be only 6 (6 digits). if more than or less than 6 digits i have provided, it has to through exception.

For Example: 123456 - valid (because it is 6-digit number)

12345 - has to through exception because i provided only 5-digit number

1234567 - has to through exception because i provided only 7-digit number

hope you understood my need and help me. Thank you.

```
import mysql.connector
import openpyxl


mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="127.0.0.1",
  user="xxxx",
  password="xxxx",
  database="xxxx"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

#mycursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE FCDB")

sp = "23|99998|211117163004|2499|5|0|4990|1|0|29259|29464|39|201116183000|39|201116183000|97830|8991000905302625027|0|1|0|0|99|1730,0630|0|0|3932196"

spl = sp.split('|')

print(spl)

#mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE rawdata (devicetype_metermaker int(10), Deviceid int(15), datetime varchar (40), voltage int(15), current int(15), powerfactor int(15), frequency int(15), contractorstatus int(15), activepower int(15), cummulative int(15), kvah int(15), MaximiumDemand int(15), MaximumDemandTime varchar(45), MaximumDemandkva int(15), Date_Time varchar (42), poweronhours int(15), simnumber varchar (50), tempercount int(10), acinputstatus int(10),  relaystatus int(10), lightstatus int(10), gsm int(10), ontime varchar(10), offtime varchar(10), doorstatus int(10), mcbstatus int(10))")

sql = "INSERT INTO rawdata (devicetype_metermaker, Deviceid, datetime, voltage, current, powerfactor, frequency, contractorstatus, activepower, cummulative, kvah, MaximiumDemand, MaximumDemandTime, MaximumDemandkva, Date_Time, poweronhours, simnumber, tempercount, acinputstatus,  relaystatus, lightstatus, gsm, ontime, offtime, doorstatus, mcbstatus) VALUES (%s, %s,%s, %s,%s, %s,%s, %s,%s, %s,%s, %s,%s, %s,%s, %s,%s, %s,%s, %s,%s, %s,%s, %s,%s, %s)"

val = (spl)

mycursor.execute(sql,val)

mydb.commit()


#mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM customers")

#myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

#for x in myresult:
  #print(x)"""

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()

SQL = 'SELECT * from  rawdata ';
mycursor.execute(SQL)
results = mycursor.fetchall()
ws = wb.active
#ws.title = "rawdata"
ws.append(mycursor.column_names)
for row in results:
  ws.append(row)

workbook_name = "test_workbook"
wb.save("data100.xlsx")
mydb.commit()
```

Comment: *Deviceid column is there, i want to validate that deviceid value, deviceid digits should be only 6 (6 digits).* Do not check entered value, forbid incorrect value insertion instead. This can be performed with according CHECK constraint in the table structure (`CHECK (DeviceID BETWEEN 100000 AND 999999)` for numeric column, for example).

Comment: Thank you, you are right but i want to validate digits (digits count),

if i  provided 6 digit number like(876545) it has to take and in case i provided 12345 (5 digit  number) or 7-digit number it has to through exception

Comment: o_O 5- or 7-digit value will fail the constraint...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Achieve this task, First i splitted my data and stored in multiple variables (number of multiple Variables must and should be same to number of rows in Table).
and next use one if statement and give conditions as below mentioned code.

```
val = (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,cc)

if(len(a)==2 and len(b)==6 and len(c)==12 and len(d)==5 and len(e)==1 and len(f)==1 and len(g)==4 and len(h)==1 and len(i)==1 and len(j)==5 and len(k)==5 and len(l)==2 and len(m)==12 and len(n)==2 and len(o)==12 and len(p)==5 and len(q)==19 and len(r)==1 and len(s)==1 and len(t)==1 and len(u)==1 and len(v)==2 and len(w)==4 and len(x)==4 and len(y)==1 and len(z)==1 and len(cc)==7):
  mycursor.execute(sql, val)

else:
  print("invalid rawdata")
```

Next everything is same.

Here is my complete updated code:

```
import mysql.connector
import openpyxl


mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="127.0.0.1",
  user="xxxx",
  password="xxxx",
  database="xxxx"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

#mycursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE FCDB")

sp = "22|016791|211117163004|24998|5|0|4990|1|0|29259|29464|39|201116183000|39|201116183000|97830|8991000905302625027|0|1|0|0|99|1730|0630|0|0|3932196"

a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,cc = sp.split('|')





#mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE rawdata (devicetype_metermaker int(10), Deviceid int(15), datetime varchar (40), voltage int(15), current int(15), powerfactor int(15), frequency int(15), contractorstatus int(15), activepower int(15), cummulative int(15), kvah int(15), MaximiumDemand int(15), MaximumDemandTime varchar(45), MaximumDemandkva int(15), Date_Time varchar (42), poweronhours int(15), simnumber varchar (50), tempercount int(10), acinputstatus int(10),  relaystatus int(10), lightstatus int(10), gsm int(10), ontime varchar(10), offtime varchar(10), doorstatus int(10), mcbstatus int(10), mcuid varchar(19))")

sql = "INSERT INTO rawdata (devicetype_metermaker, Deviceid, datetime, voltage, current, powerfactor, frequency, contractorstatus, activepower, cummulative, kvah, MaximiumDemand, MaximumDemandTime, MaximumDemandkva, Date_Time, poweronhours, simnumber, tempercount, acinputstatus,  relaystatus, lightstatus, gsm, ontime, offtime, doorstatus, mcbstatus, mcuid) VALUES (%s,%s,%s, %s,%s, %s,%s, %s,%s, %s,%s, %s,%s, %s,%s, %s,%s, %s,%s, %s,%s, %s,%s, %s,%s, %s,%s)"

val = (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,cc)

if(len(a)==2 and len(b)==6 and len(c)==12 and len(d)==5 and len(e)==1 and len(f)==1 and len(g)==4 and len(h)==1 and len(i)==1 and len(j)==5 and len(k)==5 and len(l)==2 and len(m)==12 and len(n)==2 and len(o)==12 and len(p)==5 and len(q)==19 and len(r)==1 and len(s)==1 and len(t)==1 and len(u)==1 and len(v)==2 and len(w)==4 and len(x)==4 and len(y)==1 and len(z)==1 and len(cc)==7):
  mycursor.execute(sql, val)

else:
  print("invalid rawdata")



mydb.commit()




#mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM customers")

#myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

#for x in myresult:
  #print(x)

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()

SQL = 'SELECT * from  rawdata ';
mycursor.execute(SQL)
results = mycursor.fetchall()
ws = wb.active
#ws.title = "rawdata"
ws.append(mycursor.column_names)
for row in results:
  ws.append(row)

workbook_name = "test_workbook"
wb.save("data100.xlsx")
mydb.commit()
```